How can call I multiple function using the same Firestore Transaction in Android
I need to call multiple functions using the same transaction Object, The use case  is when I need to make sure that all functions execute effectively or None for instance when money is transferred I need to make sure the user balance is decreased, the other user balance  is increased and history of this money exchange is save. (It's not a real money app, don't ask why I am doing this in client side).
My question is this function execute(list of functions) sometimes gives appropriate results sometimes it skips some functions OR I am not sure, but the data in Firestore Database says it all. They are sometimes partially written and sometimes full written.
fun execute(functions: List<(Transaction) -> Unit>) {
    if (_loadingState.value == LoadingState.Loading) return //Avoid double tapping
    _loadingState.value = LoadingState.Loading
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            Firebase.firestore.runTransaction { transaction ->
                for (function in functions) {
                    function(transaction)
                }
            }.addOnSuccessListener {
                _loadingState.value = LoadingState.Success
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                _loadingState.value =
                    LoadingState.Error("Failed, Error occurred: ${it.message}")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _loadingState.value = LoadingState.Error("Failed, Error occurred: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}

Should I remove the viewModelScope.launch should I put a return value in the runTransaction block. I need the actual solution as I said the problem is not predictable so to test/debug I need to experiment on real data and after even 10 to 30 calls the transaction partial writes can appear.
fun assignSender(user: User, order: Order) {
    if (user.userID.isBlank() || user.name.isBlank() || user.userID == order.sendBy) return
    _actionStarted = true
    val functions = listOf<(Transaction) -> Unit> { transaction ->
        assignSenderTransaction(transaction, user, order)
        HistoryViewModel.saveHistory(transaction, HistoryViewModel.toHistoryAssign(order, user))
    }
    execute(functions)
}

This is one example where I call execute  I  basically use the function execute with function that takes at least one transaction argument. The other functions are:
 private fun assignSenderTransaction(transaction: Transaction, user: User, order: Order) {
    val orderRef = firestore
        .collection(Collections.ORDERS).document(order.id)
    val updates =
        mapOf("sendBy" to user.userID, "senderName" to user.name, "senderPhone" to user.phone)
    transaction.update(orderRef, updates)
}

fun saveHistory(transaction: Transaction, history: History) {
        val historyRef = Firebase.firestore
            .collection(Collections.HISTORYS).document(history.id)
        transaction.set(historyRef, history)
}

All I do is make sure Reading Functions starts before Writing Ones. In case of this function sometimes history is not written.
UPDATE:
There is this function here after I have reviewed all the code, I find does not follow Firestore limits of 1 write per second rule AND also some of the map-field-fields may have special characters like products={"key+-":5} which might not be the way dot syntax works
fun incrementStock(
        transaction: Transaction,
        userID: String,
        userName: String,
        products: HashMap<String, Int>,
        increase: Boolean
    ) {
        val stockRef = Firebase.firestore.collection(Collections.STOCKS).document(userID)
        for ((product, quantity) in products) {
            transaction.update(
                stockRef,
                "products.$product",
                FieldValue.increment(if (increase) quantity.toLong() else -quantity.toLong())
            )
        }
        HistoryViewModel.saveHistory(
            transaction,
            HistoryViewModel.toHistory(products, userID, userName, increase)
        )
    }

Can the transaction succeed even if some of the writes in the loop fail as long as the the document was updated at least once? If the key in the products map has characters like _-=+ will the map.fieldOfMap fail to write? If yes does  it guarantee the transaction will also fail?

Without seeing your list of functions, we can't say why it "sometimes gives appropriate results sometimes it skips some functions".  For all we know, the problem could be in the functions themselves. Your question should have all the code required so that someone can copy it and observe the same unexpected result.

I am editing to add one of the situation where I call the function.

What specifically about your code doesn't work the way you expect?  We should be able to copy what you have and observe the same result compared to your stated expectations.  Please edit the question to share your debugging details.

Although I  might say when I have a  reading function before a  writting function  or  a  number of  functions some  may  be written some may  not. I am not sure if it is due to lifecycle issues  or firebase.

There is nothing to share in deep because I can not reproduce the error from the example above some transaction function can be called while others not, for instance in the example above sender might be assigned by history not written

Do you think that batch writes might help?

I am still hunting the bug on my firestore data I have updated the question  with a function I know  I have to change but is it  the real  culprit @DougStevenson
